# Enable TLS handshake debug verbose in Websphere Liberty running on an OCP pod

Tags: java, ssl, openshift, websphere

How to configure TLS handshake debug verbose in Websphere Liberty running on an OCP pod.

In TWAS admin console this was configured as follows for the J2EE app start up at node cell level.
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose:keymanager:trustmanager -Djava.security.debug=access:stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `jvm.options` file in the your "server" directory (where the `server.xml` file is located if you dont have it and add the property there.

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

In gerneral, that is the file for any JVM params you want to pass, so you can experiment with your previous settings also if the one above would be too broad.

See additional info in SSL troubleshooting page - https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mustgather-ssl-problems-websphere-liberty
There you will see how to setup additional trace string for `logging` config element.